# Remote Desktop via VPN from Mac to Windows Vista

Tags: windows, mac, windows-vista, remote-desktop

I have some problems connecting to my office from home. I'm getting the following error message:

> Remote Desktop Connection cannot verify the identity of the computer that you want to connect to.
>
> Try reconnecting to the Windows-based computer, or contact our administrator.

I have downloaded CoRD, and for some reason, that works okay. I can also connect from a Windows 7 running on VMWare Fusion. On Windows 7, I use SonicWall Global VPN Client, and on the Mac, I use VPN tracker, if that is related...

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer myself:

In Remote Desktop Preferences, go to Security-tab, and select the option 'Always connect, even if authentication fails'.

**Some more info:**
The error I got, means that the remote desktop client could not verify that the remote machine is the machine that I wanted to connect to.

> In Remote Desktop Connection, server
>   authentication verifies that you are
>   connecting to the correct remote
>   computer or server. This security
>   measure helps prevent you from
>   connecting to a different computer or
>   server than you intend to connect to.
>   This also prevents you from
>   unintentionally exposing confidential
>   information.
>   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925876

So by telling the remote desktop client to connect, even though the verification failed, the problem was solved.

Apparently, there are some settings related to this issue that can be tweaked on the remote machine, but I have not tried any of them. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753945(WS.10).aspx

Nor have I done any research to find out why the client can't verify the remote server.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your solution for those of us who might be suffering from the same problem? Thanks!